# How to fix "panic occured switching to text console"?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Panic occurred switching to text console in netbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76594/panic-occurred-switching-to-text-console-in-netbook)

Occasionly ubuntu 11.10 freezes and a black screen states "panic occured switching to text      console".

But after switiching off and switching it on again everything is fine

Comment: The same situation happened with my netbook Asus 10" today. People we need help urgently, please be so kind to share your experience in this problem. Thank you.