# "panic occurred switching back to text console"

Tags: 11.10, laptop, ubuntu-netbook, hp

I installed Ubuntu on a HP Mini 210, and everything was fine. However, after using the laptop for a while I got the error:

> panic occurred switching back to text console

What could be the reason and what can I do about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Panic occurred switching to text console in netbook](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76594/panic-occurred-switching-to-text-console-in-netbook)

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's a bug in kernel 3.0 and it happens in many netbooks. I've read that if you upgrade your kernel version up to the 3.1 branch it won't happen again.

--

Parece que es un bug en la versión 3.0 del kernel y que les pasa a muchos netbooks. He leído que si actualizas el kernel hasta una versión 3.1 deja de pasar.

Comment: +1. First time I've seen multilang answer on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if there might be an issue with your graphics driver or Xorg. I seem to recall having experienced something similar. If you press alt+ctrl+f1 you should be able to log in. There, run `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`. That should close all your apps and the window system should restart. If it doesn't, I'm afraid you'll need to reboot.

Comment: Just experienced a similar sounding error (for the first time in my personal computer history), using a flaky wifi connection on my Thinkpad x41 (with SSD); *nothing* worked, had to pull the plug!

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot in [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) to diagnose the problem.